# Uniswap v3 liquidity

Tags: uniswap

Now that uniswap and pancakeswap are migrated to the new v3 core system, do I need to change my liquidity code somehow?

Right now I have this code with the old v2 routers, factory and pair codes to add liquidity to pancakeswap. But if I'm correct this will add it to the old LP.

```
interface IPancakeFactory {
event PairCreated(address indexed token0, address indexed token1, address pair, uint);

function feeTo() external view returns (address);
function feeToSetter() external view returns (address);

function getPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external view returns (address pair);
function allPairs(uint) external view returns (address pair);
function allPairsLength() external view returns (uint);

function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external returns (address pair);

function setFeeTo(address) external;
function setFeeToSetter(address) external;


interface IPancakePair {
event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);

function name() external pure returns (string memory);
function symbol() external pure returns (string memory);
function decimals() external pure returns (uint8);
function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint);
function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);

function approve(address spender, uint value) external returns (bool);
function transfer(address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) external returns (bool);

function DOMAIN_SEPARATOR() external view returns (bytes32);
function PERMIT_TYPEHASH() external pure returns (bytes32);
function nonces(address owner) external view returns (uint);

function permit(address owner, address spender, uint value, uint deadline, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) external;

event Mint(address indexed sender, uint amount0, uint amount1);
event Burn(address indexed sender, uint amount0, uint amount1, address indexed to);
event Swap(
    address indexed sender,
    uint amount0In,
    uint amount1In,
    uint amount0Out,
    uint amount1Out,
    address indexed to
);
event Sync(uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1);

function MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY() external pure returns (uint);
function factory() external view returns (address);
function token0() external view returns (address);
function token1() external view returns (address);
function getReserves() external view returns (uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1, uint32 blockTimestampLast);
function price0CumulativeLast() external view returns (uint);
function price1CumulativeLast() external view returns (uint);
function kLast() external view returns (uint);

function mint(address to) external returns (uint liquidity);
function burn(address to) external returns (uint amount0, uint amount1);
function swap(uint amount0Out, uint amount1Out, address to, bytes calldata data) external;
function skim(address to) external;
function sync() external;

function initialize(address, address) external



interface IPancakeRouter01 {
function factory() external pure returns (address);
function WETH() external pure returns (address);

function addLiquidity(
    address tokenA,
    address tokenB,
    uint amountADesired,
    uint amountBDesired,
    uint amountAMin,
    uint amountBMin,
    address to,
    uint deadline
) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB, uint liquidity);
function addLiquidityETH(
    address token,
    uint amountTokenDesired,
    uint amountTokenMin,
    uint amountETHMin,
    address to,
    uint deadline
) external payable returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH, uint liquidity);
function removeLiquidity(
    address tokenA,
    address tokenB,
    uint liquidity,
    uint amountAMin,
    uint amountBMin,
    address to,
    uint deadline
) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB);
function removeLiquidityETH(
    address token,
    uint liquidity,
    uint amountTokenMin,
    uint amountETHMin,
    address to,
    uint deadline
) external returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH);
function removeLiquidityWithPermit(
    address tokenA,
    address tokenB,
    uint liquidity,
    uint amountAMin,
    uint amountBMin,
    address to,
    uint deadline,
    bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB);
function removeLiquidityETHWithPermit(
    address token,
    uint liquidity,
    uint amountTokenMin,
    uint amountETHMin,
    address to,
    uint deadline,
    bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
) external returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH);
function swapExactTokensForTokens(
    uint amountIn,
    uint amountOutMin,
    address[] calldata path,
    address to,
    uint deadline
) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
function swapTokensForExactTokens(
    uint amountOut,
    uint amountInMax,
    address[] calldata path,
    address to,
    uint deadline
) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
    external
    payable
    returns (uint[] memory amounts);
function swapTokensForExactETH(uint amountOut, uint amountInMax, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
    external
    returns (uint[] memory amounts);
function swapExactTokensForETH(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
    external
    returns (uint[] memory amounts);
function swapETHForExactTokens(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
    external
    payable
    returns (uint[] memory amounts);

function quote(uint amountA, uint reserveA, uint reserveB) external pure returns (uint amountB);
function getAmountOut(uint amountIn, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) external pure returns (uint amountOut);
function getAmountIn(uint amountOut, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) external pure returns (uint amountIn);
function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
function getAmountsIn(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);



interface IPancakeRouter02 is IPancakeRouter01 {
function removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
    address token,
    uint liquidity,
    uint amountTokenMin,
    uint amountETHMin,
    address to,
    uint deadline
) external returns (uint amountETH);
function removeLiquidityETHWithPermitSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
    address token,
    uint liquidity,
    uint amountTokenMin,
    uint amountETHMin,
    address to,
    uint deadline,
    bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
) external returns (uint amountETH);

function swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
    uint amountIn,
    uint amountOutMin,
    address[] calldata path,
    address to,
    uint deadline
) external;
function swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
    uint amountOutMin,
    address[] calldata path,
    address to,
    uint deadline
) external payable;
function swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
    uint amountIn,
    uint amountOutMin,
    address[] calldata path,
    address to,
    uint deadline
) external;
```

Do I need to, and how do I deploy it to the new LPs.
Thanks

Comment: + i want to have a fee of 4%, so thats why i am adding through solidity

Comment: Just in case it isn't common knowledge - for anyone who cares or who could get caught out legally - the v3 contracts are licensed -> https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v3-core/blob/main/LICENSE

Comment: Hi @Newtothescene, did you find out the answer to your question? I'm facing the same doubt